# Increase Progress Bar by increase in time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

everyone, I have this project I am building for a client that needs a kind of like progress bar indicator showing when a user subscription plan would expire say for instance a user registered at **X amount** of days and the plan is supposed to end in the next 7days after(in which user trial would be completed).

here is the logic i am using, but it doesn't seem to work, any better ideal or way to go around it would be better.

User Registered date returns 2018-09-11 16:32:08.000000 - (LARAVEL CARBON) saved in DB

and then I add 7 days to it using the below code
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', 2018-09-11 16:32:08.000000;

User Trail Expire Date Ends 2018-09-18 16:32:08.000000 - Not Saved in DB.

in my view, I have this div containing bootstrap progress indicator.

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 20%">
<span class="sr-only">20%Complete (danger)</span>
</div>
```

Again the question is, how do I loop through or Switch case between every day that passes by to at least indicate the progress, say for instance if the date is a day older add make a variable return 20% - which I can place in the progress div

Comment: just do a percent of the seconds,  I don't know the math off the top of my head but Carbon is just a DateTime wrapper, you can do `Carbon->getTimestamp()`

Comment: its exactly where i am lost, i cant seem to figure out wht right logic to work , please if you figure out the maths i would be v. greatful.

Comment: oh, I know what the math is, I don't know if you want time left, or time elapsed ... lol

Comment: i just need time left, so i can do some logic with it

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Laravel, but I would say something like this

```
$Carbon = New Carbon($row['subscribe_date']); //not sure how you do this
//expire 7 days after original date
$Carbon ->modify('+7 days'); 
$expire = $Carbon->getTimestamp();

$percent = round(($expire / time())*100);

if($percent <= 0) //expired
```

I might be wrong on the math as I am just sort of winging it.

You might have to do something like this, depending if you want "time remaining" or "elapsed time"

```
$percent = round(100-($expire / time())*100));
if($percent > 100) //expired
```

For example take these two Unix timestamps:

```
// 2018-9-9 / 2018-9-16 = 99.99 something.
// and maybe you want the something, the 00.01 bit.
 1536451200 / 1537056000
```

I've looked at Carbon, it's just an extension of DateTime, this way it's accurate to the second.

Then of course you need to return it as JSON, I am sure there is some cool Laravel way to do that.

If you want the days then you can subtract the two and divide by the number of seconds in a day.

```
   $seconds = time() - $Carbon->getTimestamp();
   if($seconds > 0 )
       $days = floor($seconds / (60*60*24));  //60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours
   else
       $days = 0;
```

And you can always do this for a timestamp if you don't like `time`

```
    (new Carbon)->getTimestamp();
```

It's just simple arithmetic.

Cheers!

Comment: Hello @ArtisticPhoenix, i tried interpreting what you wrote above an ths was the result - when not rouded up - 1.0005319508142 , when rounded up 1,

Comment: Modify works for Carbon as well, it's just a extension of `DateTime`, a.k.a  for people that cant remember that `+7 Days` adds 7 days that have `addDays`.  I've looked at the source code for it :).  No biggie though.

Comment: I woudn't echo `trail ended'`  because you are changing the data type from an int  to a string.  I would just echo `100`, also if you use backtic ` it make it a inline code block in the comments.